# How to fetch NSSet from Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a Person class and a Brand class that are a relationship in Core Data.  I know how to fetch the entire Person class (NSManagedObject), but how do I drill down to only fetch the brand associated with the person?

```
    import Foundation
    import CoreData

    class Person: NSManagedObject {

        @NSManaged var name: String
        @NSManaged var brands: NSSet

        func addBrandsObject(value: Brand) {
            self.mutableSetValueForKey("brands").addObject(value)
        }

    }

import Foundation
import CoreData

class Brand: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var people: NSSet


}
```

Viewcontroller:

```
![import UIKit
import CoreData

    class BrandsTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {


        var brands = \[NSManagedObject\]()
        var selectedPerson: Person?
        var selectedBrand: Brand?

        //Fetch Core Data
        override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            self.fetchCoreData()
        }

        //Helper Function to Fetch Core Data
        func fetchCoreData() {
            //1
            let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

            //2
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")

            //3
            var error: NSError?

            let fetchedResults =
            managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
                error: &error) as? \[NSManagedObject\]

            if let results = fetchedResults {
                ////what here? 
            } else {
                println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }][1]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have the person instance, just access the relationship:

```
    for person in results {
        let brandSet = person.brands
    }
```

No fetch required.

This is assuming of course that your relationship from `Person` to `Brand` is called `brands`.

There will also be some casting to go around, can't have swift without casting...

Comment: I tried but get NSManagedObject does not have a member named 'brands'?  See my edited question...posted XCDatamodel

Comment: As I said, you will need to do some casting thanks to Swift.  Cast the results into `[Person]`.  That is assuming you have a `NSManagedObject` subclass for `Person`.  If not, then you will need to either A) subclass `NSManagedObject` or B) use `valueForKey` to get to the relationship.

Comment: This got rid of the error:                                                                              if let results = fetchedResults as? [Person] {
            for selectedPerson in results {
                let brandSet = selectedPerson.brands
                println(brandSet)

Comment: but my console log comes back "Relationship 'brands' fault on managed object (0x7fcd186414c0) <Sizes.Person: 0x7fcd186414c0> (entity: Person; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://8CC7EED0-C454-4CA7-8B08-816963496908/Person/p1> ; data: {
    brands = "<relationship fault: 0x7fcd1840a510 'brands'>"

Comment: Correct, because the object is not realized yet.  It is still a fault (not in memory).  As soon as you touch it, Core Data will realize the fault and the full object will be available.  This is covered in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-SW8).

Comment: Thank you for the link, so then...do I call refreshObject on Person prior to pulling out the brands?

Comment: No, you do nothing unusual.  As soon as you touch the objects they will be faulted into memory.  Treat them like normal objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78965/discussion-between-psu-sabes-and-marcus-s-zarra).

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it that what you are fetching is a "Person" object and then you can iterate through brands.

```
//Helper Function to Fetch Core Data
func fetchCoreData() {
    //1
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")

    //3
    var error: NSError?

    var people =
        managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
        error: &error) as! [Person]

    // Get all brands from all people
    for (var x=0; x<people.count; x++) {
        let brands: NSArray = people[x].brands.allObjects

        for brand in brands {
            println(brand.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That really doesn't tell him how to traverse the relationship to the `Brand` set.

Comment: This wasn't what I was looking for exactly, but it's does return the brands I wanted